# When is "Try" supposed to be used in C# method names?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

We were discussing with our coworkers on what it means if the method name starts with "Try".

There were the following opinions:

- Use "Try" when the method can return a null value.
- Use "Try" when the method will not throw an exception.

What is the official definition? What does "Try" say in the method name? **Is there some official guideline about this?**

Comment: +1 People who put this much thought into the names of their functions are actually looking out for "the next guy". Not sure why this is getting close votes (and that's coming from a guy who's cast *a lot* of them tonight.)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, it got close votes because _"As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."_

Comment: There *is* an official statement by Microsoft that answers the question (see my answer). How is that not a fact?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi as Erik mentioned, it is supported by facts. Also, there are plenty of very experienced C# developers here who have *specific expertise* to provide a valid answer. Hell, Eric Lippert is the chief C# language architect. I think you can call that *specific expertise*.

Comment: The question is open to debate. You can't force a team to follow a particular naming convention, and everybody will have their own conventions, supported by whatever experience they have had. There is no _right answer_ to this question is all I'm saying : every answer is just as correct as the next.

Comment: @ErikSchierboom That it's the MS guideline is fact.  That the MS guideline is the correct guideline to use is subjective and debatable.

Comment: @Servy that the MS best practices guidelines are the correct one for a MS-specified language is not really debatable.

Comment: @Servy Well I think that in most cases one should definitely go with the official Microsoft recommendations. And more specifically, in this case I feel that the recommendation is actually a very sound and sensible one.

Comment: @Falanwe Sure it is.  MS has, in some instances, best practices that just don't make sense at all and that have a *lot* to be gained by discarding.  That they created the language doesn't mean that all of their best practices are the best ones, just like Oracle doesn't always have the only best practices that you should use in Java.  In fact, I find a significant number of MS given best practices to be at least not exactly correct.

Comment: @ErikSchierboom That the MS guideline in this specific case is appropriate to you (or even me) doesn't change the fact that it's an opinion.  It's not a question of fact, and thus isn't an appropriate question on this site.

Comment: I asked a related question a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505391/is-there-a-name-for-this-pattern

Answer (score 172, accepted):

This is known as the **TryParse** pattern and has been documented by Microsoft. The [official Exceptions and Performance MSDN page says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exceptions-and-performance):

> Consider the TryParse pattern for members that may throw exceptions in common scenarios to avoid performance problems related to exceptions.

Thus if you have code for which a regular use case would mean that it might throw an exception (such as parsing an int), the **TryParse** pattern makes sense.

Comment: Another useful link that documents this pattern (search for TryParse) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/03/16/396787.aspx

Comment: Basically, if you have a TryParse method, you should have a Parse method that throws when TryParse would return false. Conversely, if you have a Parse method, you should consider having a TryParse method that return false when Parse would throw

Comment: +1. Just to add to this, exceptions are generally for "exceptional" circumstances. If you're doing something that could easily fail and that failure is not particularly notable, then using this pattern is more idiomatic than a try/catch

Comment: Did such a pattern really require guidelines from Microsoft? Seems fairly basic stuff.

Comment: It _is_ basic stuff, but that doesn't mean that guidelines are not useful. Getting basic stuff right can be quite hard if you don't know the platform well enough.

Comment: Is there any preferred pattern for including a `Try` method in a covariant interface?  One couldn't have a `VariantLookup<out TValue>` interface include a `bool TryGetValue(object key, out TValue value)` but the interface could include `TValue TryGetValue(object key, out bool success)` [the use of `object` for the key would allow code to ask a collection of `Cat` whether it contains an `Animal`--if asked to look up Fido (an instance of `Dog`), the collection would simply indicate that it does not contain Fido].  Is the latter a good pattern, or is some other one preferred?

Comment: @daveL: It's basic, yes, but a different convention (`ParseOrNull` and `Parse`) or even the opposite convention (`Parse` and `ParseOrThrow`) would be just as basic. The benefit of guidelines from Microsoft is that it promotes consistency: when you look at a codebase you're not familiar with, you can still understand it, because it (most likely) uses the widespread conventions endorsed by the proprietors of the platform.

Comment: Often missed when quoting from this official guidance is this bit: "When using this pattern, it is important to define the try functionality in strict terms. If the member fails for any reason other than the well-defined try, the member must still throw a corresponding exception." So in fact Try methods can and should throw exceptions in some cases.

Answer (score 135):

*(Corrected)* There is official guideline, as Erik suggested.

When I see `TrySomething` method, I assume it

- doesn't throw
- returns `bool`
- if I expect value, it is returned via 'out' parameter
- there exists `Something` method, that allows me to handle any exception myself. *(edit, suggested by Jesse Webb)*

Comment: Correction - It has official guideline. See Erik's answer.

Comment: +1 But I also have a 4th expectation: If there is a `TryFoo` method, there will be a similar `Foo` method which allows me to handle any `` exceptions myself. These methods' signatures will likely be different so their usages are not interchangeable without other code changes.

Comment: @JesseWebb, thanks for pointing that out. I've added your comment into my answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: "Doesn't throw" seems to me overgeneralized.  For example, Int32.TryParse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Int32) throws ArgumentException if it doesn't like the style parameter.

Comment: I agree that "doesn't throw" could be considered overgeneralized, but I believe the intent was to convey that it doesn't throw as a result of execution rather than as a result of the value of the parameters.

Answer (score 10):

I think you should use `try` when you want to proceed. It doesn't matter that a method returns some value or not.

Case 1: if it returns fine, you can proceed in some way.

Case 2: if it does not return: it is still fine; you can proceed in some other way.

And if you expect some value as output of that method then use the `out` parameter.

#### Example

```
int value
if (dictionary.TryGetValue("key", out value))
{
    // Proceed in some way
}
else
{
    // Proceed in some other way
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to use "Try" in method name, when you want to manifest the fact that the method invokation can produce not valid result. Following the .NET standard it's, by the way, not a function that raises an exception, but the function that returns some `VALID` or `NON_VALID`, from the program perspective, value.

At the end, this all about naming convention you decide to use in your group.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to include `try` in your methodname if:

- you don't throw any exception
- your method has the following signature: `bool TrySomething(input, out yourReturn)`

So basically if we use `try`-methods we only get a boolean result back.

So the following code will not throw any exceptions:

```
string input = "blabla";
int number;
if (int.TryParse(input, out number))
{
// wooohooo we got an int!
} else
{
//dooh!
}
```

Whereas this code can (and in this case will) throw exceptions:

```
string input = "blabla";
int number;
try
{
     number = int.Parse(input); //throws an exception
}
catch (Exception)
{
     //dooh!
}
```

Using Try methods is a safer and more defensive way to code.
Also the code snippet #2 takes more performance to execute if it's not an integer.

Comment: Your code snippet #2 should read `int number = int.Parse(input);` if you want it to be more meaningful in this context.

Comment: You are still missing the `int number;` declaration before the try block and the `number = ...` assignment.

Comment: @PierreArnaud Thank you, I also included 'int number' now.

Comment: Note that you may still throw exceptions if the exception is somewhat unrelated to the direct action being performed, like `TryLoadFile(path, out file)` woah, out of RAM. So the caller would expect no errors for a bad path or access denied, but an exception for the whackier things that could also go wrong. And document it.

Answer (score -1):

TLDR:
I'm going to give this a shot, because this simple question gave me a lot of pause:

**A method returning a boolean indicating success should only be named 'TryX' when there is only a single obvious reason for falure.**

### Explination

There's an interesting slant to this that I think we have to consider.  The [TryParse pattern as it is named by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exceptions-and-performance#try-parse-pattern) is named specifically for a reason - **using 'TryX' *might* be considered an anti-pattern and they are trying to avoid expansion of it's use**.

If the Tester-Doer pattern tests and then executes, then an execute and then test pattern might be called Doer-Tester.  However, there is a fundamental difference.  In a Tester-Doer the doer still throws an exception on failure.  This is not the case in this TryX Doer-Tester.

This presents a pit-of-success problem.  You now have code that *might* do absolutely nothing.  At best you don't know why it failed.  In the case of a forgotten if/test, creates odd, red-herring bugs farther into the code.

I'm not afraid to admit that this is conjecture.  But when I first saw "TryParse" as a pattern name, I thought how could they be so lazy...and then I thought maybe they weren't.

With parse, there is really a single reason that an exception can be thrown - that the input string was not in the correct format.  And so it is understood what a return value of false means.

But in a generic case, that can't be said - there may be multiple failure reasons.  You are very quickly getting into other best practice considerations and debates like the [case for throwing exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46982339/852208) and [minimizing try/catch blocks and the associated logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973642/how-using-try-catch-for-exception-handling-is-best-practice).

I'm not saying that there's isn't the occasional application of this pattern. I  suppose there are places in background threads and during shutdown or logging attempts where if it goes bad there, your options for recovery grow slim.  But is there really nothing you can do?  I think that's the question we're meant to ask before we rely on an established pattern that lets us write methods that may or may not do what they are supposed to do.

I'll close with a new "Yoda" rule.  - Do or do not, there is no try.