# Is there a way that I can simplify setting a value based on what is contained in a string?

Tags: c#

Presently my code is like this but I am wondering if there is a way that I could simplify it. What I am looking for is for one of the strings "JLPT N1","JLPT N2","JLPT N3","JLPT N4","JLPT N5" and then when I see one of these I will set the value of a `phraseSources[seq].JishoJlpt`.

Note that only one of the above can appear at once.

```
            if (nodes2[0].InnerText.Contains("JLPT N5"))
            {
                phraseSources[seq].JishoJlpt = "5";
            }
            if (nodes2[0].InnerText.Contains("JLPT N4"))
            {
                phraseSources[seq].JishoJlpt = "4";
            }
            if (nodes2[0].InnerText.Contains("JLPT N3"))
            {
                phraseSources[seq].JishoJlpt = "3";
            }
            if (nodes2[0].InnerText.Contains("JLPT N2"))
            {
                phraseSources[seq].JishoJlpt = "2";
            }
            if (nodes2[0].InnerText.Contains("JLPT N1"))
            {
                phraseSources[seq].JishoJlpt = "1";
            }
```

Would appreciate if anyone can suggest how I can simplify this.

Comment: is the N1,2,3.. going to be more than 9 ?

Comment: Do you control the format of the JSON data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look into `Regular Expressions`.

This method would grab the `int` from your text, which you could then use.

```
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public int ContainedNum(string s)
    {
        var match = Regex
           .Match(s, (@"JLPT N(\d{1})"))
           .Groups
           .Cast<Group>()
           .Skip(1) // the first match is the entire string not the group
           .Single()
           .Value;
        var num = int.Parse(match);
        return num;
    }
```

This assumes that *every argument* always follows this pattern and doesn't go bigger than `9`. If that isn't the case you would need to be more conservative using `Single()` and figure out what you want to return if that isn't case.

You could use it like this:

```
var text = nodes2[0].InnerText;
var num = ContainedNum(text);
phraseSources[seq].JishoJlpt = num.ToString();
```

Comment: Wouldn't `^JLPT N(\d{1:3})` work for 1-3 digit numbers, for example, with no other changes?

Comment: Since the OP uses `Contains` I don't think you want to use the `^` anchor.  Also there doesn't seem to be much point in parsing the number to an `int` to just turn around and format it back to a `string`.

Comment: @juharr Good call. I removed the `^`. I realised the casting to an `int` is unnecessary, but when working with numbers I like to make that explicit in the `signature`.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [Try pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207712/when-is-try-supposed-to-be-used-in-c-sharp-method-names) for this kind of parsing:

```
private static bool TryParseJLPT(string text, out int value)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(text, @"JLPT N(?<Number>\d+)", RegexOptions.None);
    if (!match.Success) { value = default; return false; }
    return Int32.TryParse(match.Groups["Number"].Value, out value);
}
```

Usage example:

```
if (TryParseJLPT(nodes2[0].InnerText, out int value))
{
    phraseSources[seq].JishoJlpt = value;
}
```

Depending on the case it may be more appropriate to throw instead of returning a boolean value. If a parsing failure is an expected case that can be handled, then the Try pattern is OK. If a parsing failure is exceptional and you don't know how to continue, then throwing is better.

Answer (score -1):

why not using an extension ?

I've been using This extension for a while :

```
internal static class Extensions
{
    public static bool In(this string value, params string[] args)
    {
        return args.Contains(value);
    }

}
```

Applying the `In` extension on your code would be like this :

```
if (nodes2[0].InnerText.In("JLPT N1","JLPT N2","JLPT N3","JLPT N4","JLPT N5"))
{
    phraseSources[seq].JishoJlpt = nodes2[0].InnerText.Last(); // get the last character
}
```

Comment: The OP's code is checking if any of those values are substrings of `InnerText`, so this will not work the same as their code.